# Visual Studios Add on ToolWindowControl where to save user settings?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a standardized place to store user configurations (and perhaps code specific configurations) when creating a ToolWindowControl?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-an-extension-with-a-tool-window?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the best resource
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/persist-and-restore-application-scope-properties